# Different touch states for IBAction

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

I remember darkly that an earlier version of Xcode provided the option to connect IBActions for  UI elements on several different states like when the user pressed down on a button but didn't lift the finger yet, etc. All I see in Xcode 6 is only one IBAction that fires when for example a button was pressed.

I need an IBAction on several buttons that gets called right when the user touches the button, even without lifting the finger. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Seriously, @S R Nayak, it is questionable if each single code word needs to be formatted in a special way. But using italic sure makes no sense at all. if you feel the urge for formatting, use code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Ya simply select the `button` and open the `connection inspector` from there you can connect several methods depending on uses's action.

[image]

or simply right-click the button and connect it from there like this

[image]

Comment: Aha, I see now what the problem is! With a UIButton these event types appear. But with a button in a toolbar or tabbar they don't. Is there any way to get this working on buttons in toolbars and tabbars?

Comment: @Avalon if you want the answer for UIBarButtonItem I can... but UITabBarItem I cann't... just tell me.

Comment: Yes please tell me how it's done for UIBarButtonItem. That's another step forward anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the event you're looking for is `UIEventTouchDown`, no lifting of the finger necessary.

Here is official Apple documentation on `UIControlEvents`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents

Answer (score 0):

You can set a differente IBAction for different events with the method:

```
addTarget:action:forControlEvents
```

List of Events:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEvents[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEvents)

Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

You can also choose differente event by the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

After your request I am writing you the second answer

1) Create a `UIView` subclass let's say `MYView` something like this.

```
#import "MYView.h"

@implementation MYView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


}

@end
```

2) Create a `UIBarButtonItem` (same trick can be applied to `UIButton` because it is directly inheriting from `UIView`) like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *yourBBI = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[MYView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)]];
```

Here we go... if you just touch (no need to release your finger) the method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

will be fired.

Hope it will help you...

Comment: Thanks for the code example @Goppinath! But I wonder can this somehow be applied also if I only define the tool bar and its buttons in a storyboard, i.e. the non-code way? You init your bar button item with a custom view class that features handlers for the touch states.

Obviously creating a sub class of UIAudibleBarButtonItem and adding e.g. the touchesBegan handler doesn't seem to cut it. I wonder why it works when initing with a custom  view class but not when extending the UIAudibleBarButtonItem class?